# Finding the absolute difference with positive and negative values

Tags: excel, math

I have two columns. One with positive values and one with negative values. I need to find the absolute difference between the two columns.

What I am currently doing is the following: First of all, I edit both the columns to make all the values positive. Then I subtract the first column with the second column. I change any negative value to the positive one. Is this the same as the absolute difference?

Comment: Abs(x-y) will always give the absolute difference regardless of the sign of x and y... No need to mess with the column values - just calculate!

Comment: abs(x-y) will give absolute difference but if the sign in x and y is same but if it is different then you wont get. Actually it will add up the value.

Comment: Subtraction should take care of that - trust me, I've got a math degree! As illustration: Abs(8 - 5) = Abs(3) = 3;  Abs((-8) - 5) = Abs(-13) = 13;  Abs((-8) - (-5)) = Abs(-3) = 3. You can think of Abs(x-y) as "the distance between x and y"

Comment: There is also a possibility that you are mixing up terminology. Absolute difference is like "the distance between x and y", and is ALWAYS positive. Signed difference is "The change from x to y" and can be negative when we have to decrease x to get to y. Do you mean signed difference instead?

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use the [ABS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/abs-HP005208978.aspx) function

```
=ABS(B1-A1)
```

Comment: If one column is positive and other column is negative then there wont be a any difference between column but actually that comes to be addition between 2 columns.  for example ABS(Column1 -(-column2)) is a addition.

Comment: If one column is 5 and the other is -1, what are you looking for the final answer to be. "Absolute difference" means the answer would be 6 but your method of ABS(ABS(A1)-ABS(A2)) will make it be 4

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you're doing is actually

```
=ABS(ABS(B1)-ABS(A1))
```

which is not the same as

```
=ABS(B1-A1)
```

for example if you have -3 and 1 the first would give you 2 and the second would give 4. I don't know which one you want.

Comment: I am not able to understand how 4 will be the difference between B1 and A1. actually difference should be 2. may be i am wrong

Comment: @user3270725: -3 - 1 = -4, and the absolute value of -4 is 4. If you don't want the answer to be 4 then I suggest you use my first formula rather than the second (which others seem to suggest).

Answer (score 2):

This works no matter which value is positive or negative:

```
=MAX(A1,B1) - MIN(A1,B1)
```

Comment: Neither MAX nor MIN are VBA functions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's a pretty clunky workaround, but it is something where I can understand what's going on and works every time.

Here is my scenario where I needed to solve this problem. I had a system stock list showing 1 of these 10 of those but also showing -10 of these and 5 of those, and once entering my physical data from doing a stock take, I had pluses and minuses all over the place, so the data looked like this:

```
Physical stocktake value     system value
0                            0
1                            0
1                            2
0                           -1
1                           -1
```

Effectively all the different connotations of pluses and minuses.

so column 'a' is actual, column b is system

I created columns c,d,e,f ..... I warned you it was a little clunky, but it is sound in the result.

```
formula in column c = '=IF(A1>B1,A1+B1,A1-B1'
formula in column D = '=IF(B1+C1<>A1,A1-B1,C1)'
formula in column E = '=IF(D1>C1,C1,D1)'
```

Column E is the data you want, it rationalises all of the pluses and Minuses in your data to show a true difference (independent of positive and negative location) for the values you require.

Someone much cleverer than I will condense this down into a singular equation, but i read up on it, tried the current solutions/advise, and didn't have a clue what the techs were going on about, so came up with this faultless solution.

It does work and it s simply a transpose the A1's and B1's for your data content.

Hope it helps (a little).

I for one will check back, just to pick up on what the clever guys and gals come back with, just a case of life is to short to drive into this level of detail for a simple solution. Sometimes simple is best.

Yeah ok, set myself up for that one ..... so I'm simple, but I know what I'm doing and understand it ........